# What does "pseudo" mean in CSS?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

When I read about CSS and HTML I cross the word pseudo-elements.

I haven't found a good short explanation for what pseudo means. Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: So you scoured Google and came up empty? I find that extremely difficult to believe.

Comment: @j08691 Read into the question a bit... I'm pretty sure the problem here is understanding how the definition applies in this case.

Comment: @Brad And? There are plenty of sources that define pseudo in general, as well as with respect to CSS and HTML. And as you can see by the flurry of short answers it's pretty easy to find definitions.

Comment: OP, is you question specifically to pseudo-elements or pseudo in genearl?

Comment: @j08691 Sure, and from the question this person has read at least some of those sources and still doesn't understand.  Sometimes on these basic sort of problems, particularly when there is a language barrier, it's hard for someone to get started at all.  While this is a bit thin for a typical Stack Overflow question, it's perfectly valid and on-topic when you consider the full context here.

Comment: I also find it ironic that no one referred the OP to SO docs (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=css&query=pseudo)

Comment: @Brad No one said it was off-topic or invalid for this site.

Comment: at first it was to pseudo in general, but now when I understand what pseudo-code is, I have it hard to understand why pseudo-elements is.

Comment: @Santi yes, you're right. The tag was unnecessary the entire time. However, the question's aim was finding out what pseudo meant, but other users took it upon themselves to turn OP's example into his primary focus, which I don't think is quite right.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Now, when I think I know what pseudo means, I have a new question. What is it in a pseudo-element that makes the pseudo-element pseudo? I hope this question made any sense to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Supposed or purporting to be but not really so; false; not genuine:

— https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pseudo-

A pseudo-element is something that acts like an element, but is not an element.

Comment: I liked this explanation => "A pseudo-element is something that acts like an element, but is not an element."

Answer (score 9):

psuedo-elements allow you to style specific *parts* of an element. Some examples of pseudo-elements are:

- `::after`
- `::before`

These specific ones allow you to add style to just after, or just before an element.

for example:

```css
.test {
    background-color: gray;
}

.test::after {
    content: ' some more text';
    color: red
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
    testing...
</div>
```

Here, we style the `.test` element normally

*BUT*, then we add a bit more *after* it using the pseudo-element selector `::after` to let us add more text and change the colour.

You can read more and see more examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Comment: Thanks but this didn't answer my question, maybe I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, "fake".

A more complete definition can be found here: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pseudo

Comment: I don't quite get why the downvotes for these 2 answers. I understood the same thing as them from the question, that OP doesn't understand what "pseudo" means, not what CSS pseudo-elements mean

Comment: Your absolutely right, these answers are exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

A pseudo element is a CSS-generated non-DOM element that is rendered as if it was a DOM element in the browser.  But it doesn't actually add a node to the DOM.  So if you inspected it in, say Chrome Dev Tools, you won't see it as a regular node.

Interestingly some screen-readers read pseudo-element content and others don't.